# Can't pull data out of ViewBag in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm trying to pull data out of ViewBag and to insert it into a form hidden field via JS, before submit.

It doesn't work.

While debug, I find that part of the JS expression is kind of ignored, and as a result, a 'var' is evaluated to an empty string.

Here's the JS part, which supposed to do the assignment:

```
function setid() {
   var id = '@(ViewBag.id)';
   $('#idField').val(id);
};
```

in debug I get the below expression, which of course leads to a null 'id':

```
function setid() {
    var id = '';
    $('#idField').val(id);
  };
```

(I'm not sure it's the only obstacle)

This JS function is being called by a 'OnBegin' argument of 'Ajax.BeginForm' on the same page.

This's the html hidden field that resides within the form, which into I'm trying to assign the 'id' value:

```
input type  ="hidden" name ="id" id ="idField" value =""
```

and the following is the Controller, which returns a Partial, that is rendered as a jquery dialog:

```
public ActionResult openDialog()
    {
        ViewBag.id = TempData["id"];
        return PartialView("EndLoadDetailsDialog");
    }
```

**Updated:**
As I think of it, I might have found the problem. Please let me know if I'm right:

The controller in which I define the viewbag value, returns a partial view, which is the last view that is beinng returned.

This partial view is rendered to a JQuery dialog. After I close it, I return to the one before, which contains a form. In the form view (the one before the last one) I'm trying to access the viewbag value via JS function, and assign it to a hidden field in the form. So actually, I'm trying to get the viewbag value, not from the view to which I've sent the viewbag.

Is it a problem? Are viewbag values available only from the last view that has rendered?

Comment: Have you debugged that `TempData["id"]` is not null in your `openDialog` action?

Comment: Yes I did. As far as I understand, the problem is in the view area..

Comment: And your `setid` method is declared in the `EndLoadDetailsDialog` partial view?

Comment: No, it's declared in the same page of the form.

Comment: yes after the UPDATE.. thats a prob.. use directly the TempData tht is meant for these purposes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. TempData is used to pass data between controllers..

Comment: Unfortunately, ViewBag properties need to be set each time a request is made. After you close your partial view, your ViewBag is flushed.