# ViewBag values accessibility in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, viewbag

The controller in which I define a viewbag value, returns a partial view, which is the last view that is beinng returned.

This partial view is rendered to a JQuery dialog.  After I close it, I return to the one before, which contains a form. In the form view (the one before the last one) I'm trying to access the viewbag value via JS function, and assign it to a hidden field in the form. So actually, I'm trying to get the viewbag value, not from the view to which I've sent the viewbag.

Is it a problem? Are viewbag values available only from the last view that has rendered?

Comment: Actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269975/cant-pull-data-out-of-viewbag-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but in any case you wouldn't normally want or need to access ViewBag outside of the view it belongs to.  It seems like there would be a couple of better options.

- populate the ViewBag value you need into a hidden field somewhere else in the DOM.
- Since you're using JQuery dialog, consider using its callback function to pass the values you need back to the main form.  See here for an example:  [jquery ui dialog box need to return value, when user presses button, but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor)

Comment: tnks for your time! I've considered these options. Using the dialog callback is not practical, since I need the value as soon as I close the dialog. I would very much want to have an answer for my question.

Comment: @Tall that doesn't make sense to me ... you said you're running some JS to access the value, right?  So why don't you pass a JS function containing that code as the callback to your JQ dialog?

Comment: I've checked one more,  and there's indeed a 'beforeClose' event. My mistake - I intend to use it. Despite my wish to get a definite answer to my question, I'll mark your comment as an answer.